# How to search for a string with regex and change only part of it?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you match using /[a-z].\s[a-z]/g but only want to change the period to a comma?

For example:

```
"asdf. Aasdfcs. adGDS$gGB. Basdf".replace(/[a-z]\.\s[a-z]/g, ", ")
```

This will match "s. a", but I want the result to be "asdf. Aasdfcs, adGDS$gGB. BasdfB" without altering the letters, just the period to a comma.  Anything could come before or after this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using capture groups, of course! Use parenthesis to form a group and `$n` to access the group:

```
"asdfcs. adGDS$gGB".replace(/([a-z])\.\s([a-z])/g, "$1, $2");
```

For your convenience, see the result with this snippet:

```js
alert("asdfcs. adGDS$gGB".replace(/([a-z])\.\s([a-z])/g, "$1, $2"));
```